# updating javascript_include_tag dynamically on show.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So here is the scenario:

I have 4 entries in a database, they are 4 map routes.

Each map route has its own XML file containing the co-ordinates of each route, I have written an ajax function to pull the data from the xml and write it to a google map

this is an extract from the code

```
$.ajax({                  
 type: 'GET',
 url: '/route4.gpx',            
 dataType: 'xml',             
 success: function(track) {
   var grids = [];         
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();  
   $(track).find('trkpt').each(function() {       
     var lat = $(this).attr('lat');            
     var lon = $(this).attr('lon');
     var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);    
     grids.push(point);                              
     bounds.extend(point);
```

I have this code saved into 4 javascript files where the URL line is different on each (route1.gpx, route2.gpx etc)

What I want to do is on the show.html.erb file is to change the javascript_include_tag to update to the relevant javascript file

So the show.html.erb tags look like the following

```
<%= javascript_include_tag  "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" ,"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js", "/js/script1.js" =%>
```

what I would like is the last reference to change when I visit a different page so

when linked to show/1  the javascript file would be "/js/script1.js"

when linked to show/2  the javascript file would be "/js/script2.js"

when linked to show/3  the javascript file would be "/js/script3.js"

when linked to show/4  the javascript file would be "/js/script4.js"

So is there anyway to write into the javascript_include_tag to achieve this?

All help/suggestions/comments appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could interpolate the string passed to javascript_include_tag, pass it as an instance variable etc, but I think you are heading down the wrong track. I would have a single javascript function that takes the url to make the ajax request to as a parameter.

You would then call that function with that parameter. You've got several choices here.

You could have a script tag where you generate the function call dynamically, ie you do something along the lines of

```
 $(function(){
   my_function(<%= @url.to_json %>)
 })
```

You could have a script tag where you set a window property with the url and use that later:

```
 window.map_url = <%= @url.to_json %>
```

and then somewhere else

```
 $(function(){
   my_function(window.map_url)
 })
```

You could have the function call be part of the static javascript, but have it pull its parameters either from the data attribute of some relevant DOM element

```
 $(function(){
   my_function($('some_element').data('url'))
 })
```

I'd usually go for the latter

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you interpolate?

```
<%= javascript_include_tag  "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" ,"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js", "/js/script#{controller_variable_for_example_id}.js" =%>
```